# PostgreSQL data comparsion tool

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a tool/command which can compare data between two PostgreSQL databases. The reason to do this is to have some external verification that the SQL script responsible for data migration from one PostgreSQL database to the other have been written correctly.

Any pointers would be appreciated
regards
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMS makes a tool which can do this.

http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/dbcomparer

Comment: Thanks we did have a look at it.

Comment: Am just making it clear here.  Above link is taking to the *database comparison* and sychronization.  OP has actually referred to `data comparison tool`, and here is the link on *data comparison* and synchronization http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/datacomparer

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL site has a nice [Software catalogue](http://www.postgresql.org/download/product-categories). Peruse the [Administration/development tools](http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/1) category.